# parsing output from net view to net use in Windows

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to make a batch script which runs the net view command, gets each VM hostname and then creates a local network drive to each VM. I am using the asterix operator to automatically assign an available drive letter rather than manually assigning each letter per VM:

net use * \VM_1_HOSTNAME username password /persist

However when I run it, I get "the system cannnot find the file specified 'view'. Even when manually pointing to the system32 folder containing net.exe.

Where have I gone wrong here? Here is my script:

```
for /f "eol=# tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('net view' /i0 %1 ^|FINDSTR     /C:"\\" )
do
(net use * %%i\%systemdrive% /persist)
```

EDIT:
Doing @NET VIEW %~1 & @PAUSE returns the following output:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>cd Desktop

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>a.bat
Server Name            Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\HP-ENVY
\\XPHOST
\\XPTEST
The command completed successfully.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I would like to pass the string "\\XPTEST" to the net share command in order to get a list of share names on \\XPTEST. I would also like to have it work if I created \\someotherXPvm, ...

It then can pass each sharename drive of each \\hostname into the net use command but in a for loop like:

```
net use %driveletter% %hostname%\%sharename% /persist
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `NET VIEW` had an `/I` option! I'm assuming that `%1` is a computername in the form `//computername`, and that you're wanting to retrieve the Share name, which I assume will be the first token of the output but it seems you're trying to retrieve the fourth token. If you were to provide an example, [as an edit in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48320043/edit), of the output you get from running just the following from a batch file, `@NET VIEW %~1 & @PAUSE`, it may help, especially if you tell us specifically what you are hoping to return as `%%i`.

Comment: @Compo I got it working almost by just typing \\hostpc\c$ instead of %myvar\C:/ and the * also works, i.e it automatically assigns free drive letters. It looks like the problem is with the parsing itself. I basically need to read the lines containing the hostnames (hence why the search string is "\\". but despite changing the token lengh it says either 'network path not found' or 'invalid command paramater. I added %1 to the  end instead of %%i (bad mistake) also.

Comment: I refer you to my last sentence!

Comment: +compo OH I thought %%i was a FOR paramater, not a variable?
running '@NET VIEW %~1 & @PAUSE' returns a list of hostnames just fine, the problem is parsing them.

Comment: I want you to post as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48320043/edit) and formatted using the `{}` button, the output from that single line command and then explain which part(s) of that output you are hoping to parse and pass to your next command.

Comment: what on earth is the `/i0` switch?

Comment: @compo I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'net view' /i0 %1 ^|FINDSTR     /C:"\\"
```

should be

```
'net view /i0 %1 ^|FINDSTR     /C:"\\" '
```

The entire command to be executed needs to be in single-quotes.